# stuck at the output of list comprehension vs for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand the behavior of for loop in list comprehension.
The output for the below normal for loop is

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'Fail' in row['Status']:
        status='Fail'
    else:
        status='Pass'
print(status)

status = pass
```

But when i am implementing the same in list comprehension, the output is not what i am expecting.

```
status=["Pass" if 'Fail' in row['Status'] else "fail" for index, row in df.iterrows()]
print(status)

output=['pass', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass']
```

How can i attend the output of for loop using list comprehension.

I am new to python looking for some guidance.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through the list in the first place? Where did you even use `i` in the loop solution?

Comment: There's no need for a loop or a list comprehension: `s = "pass" if 2 in lst else "fail"`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But the actual input and code is bit different. Just created a scenario here.
`for index, row in df_cap.iterrows():
                if 'Fail' in row['Status']:
                    cap_status='Fail'
                else:
                    cap_status='Pass'`

Comment: Still, a list comprehension is probably not appropriate here. Just set `cap_status = 'Pass'` before the loop then only set 'Fail' in the loop if the condition is met. `break` on that condition. A loop with a `break` will only check _up to_ the first false condition. A list comprehension will check the _entire_ list.

Comment: I was trying to use list comprehension to optimize my code. Any way to attend the same using comprehensions ?

Answer (score 0):

Well that output is to be expected. But I don't seem to understand what you're trying to do.

The following part in the first code snippet:

```
if 2 in lst:
        s='pass'
    else:
        s='fail'
```

is always going to assign 'pass' to the variable s.

And this part in the second code snippet:

```
'pass' if 2 in lst else 'fail'
```

is always going to return 'pass'.

So why are you running this code multiple times in a for loop or a list comprehension.

The difference between the 2 snippets is that in the first one you rewrite the value of s every loop, so only the last iteration of the loop writes the value of s you will print (but again this is always the same value: 'pass'). And in the second code snippet you do a list comprehension, which will save the value you calculate every time as a new item of the list. That's why you have a list with the value 'pass' 4 times.

If you just want to check if 2 is in the list you don't need a for loop or a list comprehension and you can rewrite the code snippets as follows:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
if 2 in lst:
    s='pass'
else:
    s='fail'
print(s)
```

and

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
result = 'pass' if 2 in lst else 'fail'
print(result)
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Could you please have a look. I need to loop through to fetch the desired column because its a data frame

Comment: Again I don't see what you're trying to do. It seems like you're looping over an entire list to get a value you can get with a single line.
Why would you loop over every value in the first snippet if you're just going to use the value of the last iteration.
And in the second snippet: why do you need a list comprehension for that? 
What do you want to achieve?